# Java: Infinite Loop

Tags: java

There are a lots of option available for infinite loop but this are mostly use `while(true) or for(;;)`

I know `while(true)` is the best option, since it is easier to understand.

But I want to use `for(;;)`.

I want to know what is going on inside of `for loop` when I we used two `;` within for loop.

`for(;;)`

Semicolon means its an empty statement. But how its works when we use inside of `for loop` for infinite execution?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question.  But I do know how to answer it.  I would compile a simple java program using the construct and then examine it with a decompiler like javap.  I would not be surprised if `while(true)` and `for(;;)` generate the same byte code.  I also would not be surprised if they differ.

Comment: @Shiladittya please consider accepting my answer if it solved your question. If not, I would be happy to elaborate further

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens:

```
for (initialization statement; condition check; increment/decrement)
    // loop body;
```

With `for(;;)`:

- There is no initialization.
- There is no condition check.
- There is no increment/decrement.

Therefore it will run forever, exactly like `while(true)`.